# Print consecutive numbers

Tags: sql-server-2000

How do i print consecutive numbers in using a single sql query  .. like 1 , 2 , 3 ...

Comment: Ummmm....I doubt if it can be done. Anyways +1 for your question.

Comment: Consecutive numbers from what to what. And what do you mean `PRINT` using a single query. `PRINT` takes a variable not a query.

Comment: And why on earth has this question got 3 upvotes? `PRINT '1 , 2 , 3 ...'` would meet the requirement at present.

Answer (score 2):

```
;with cte
as 
(
select 1 [sequence]
union all
select [sequence]+1 from cte where [sequence]<100
)
select * from cte
```

try,By using Common type expression we can do it.....Its working

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I've understood your question correctly, but if you just want to `PRINT` consecutive numbers I don't see why you couldn't do the following:

```
DECLARE @a INT
SET @a = 1
WHILE @a <= 10
BEGIN
PRINT @a
SET @a += 1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the line number in the sql result set? try the following:

```
SET @line = 0; 
SELECT @line := @line + 1, some_field FROM table_name;
```

For SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SalesYTD DESC) AS 'Row Number',     SalesYTD, PostalCode 

FROM Sales.vSalesPerson

WHERE TerritoryName IS NOT NULL AND SalesYTD <> 0;
```

Comment: That looks like MySQL syntax.

Comment: oh, sorry, sql server seems have a similar thing: ROW_NUMBER() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: Not in 2000 it doesn't. There is a very similar technique in SQL Server to concatenate strings though. That could probably be used to increment a variable as well but you would be relying on a table of the correct size to be available.

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

```
  select
            (a3.id + a2.id + a1.id + a0.id) as id
        FROM 
        /* create the tables to be used for the cartesian join */
        (
            select 0 id UNION ALL 
            select 1 UNION ALL
            select 2 UNION ALL
            select 3 UNION ALL
            select 4 UNION ALL
            select 5 UNION ALL
            select 6 UNION ALL
            select 7 UNION ALL
            select 8 UNION ALL
            select 9
        ) as a0,    
        (
            select 0 id UNION ALL
            select 10 UNION ALL
            select 20 UNION ALL
            select 30 UNION ALL
            select 40 UNION ALL
            select 50 UNION ALL
            select 60 UNION ALL
            select 70 UNION ALL
            select 80 UNION ALL
            select 90  
        ) as a1, 
        (
            select 0 id UNION ALL
            select 100 UNION ALL
            select 200 UNION ALL
            select 300 UNION ALL
            select 400 UNION ALL
            select 500 UNION ALL
            select 600 UNION ALL
            select 700 UNION ALL
            select 800 UNION ALL
            select 900
        ) as a2, 
        (
            select 0 id UNION ALL
            select 1000 UNION ALL
            select 2000 
        ) as a3 
    order by id asc ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @NUM INT, @COUNT INT , @NUM1 INT , @SPACE INT
SET @NUM=1 SET @COUNT=1000 SET @NUM1=0 

WHILE(@NUM<=@COUNT)

BEGIN

WHILE (@NUM1<=@NUM) 

BEGIN
DECLARE @STORE VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @NUM1=@NUM1+1 --1
SET @SPACE = (@COUNT-@NUM) --3

SET @STORE=ISNULL(@STORE,'')+SPACE(1)+CAST(@NUM1 AS VARCHAR(MAX))--1
PRINT (SPACE(@SPACE)+@STORE)

IF(@NUM<=@COUNT)
BEGIN
SET @NUM=@NUM+1
END
END


SET @NUM1=0

END
```

To print numbers in triangular format

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @digits table (id int,value int )
insert @digits values (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,6),(1,8),(1,9),(1,10),(1,12),
(2,8),(2,9),(2,11),(2,12),
(3,2),(3,4),(3,5),(3,7)

select distinct id,stuff(convert(varchar(max),
(
    select 
        ',' + case 
            when min(value) = max(value) then convert(varchar(10), min(value)) 
            else convert(varchar(10), min(value)) + '-' + convert(varchar(10), max(value)) 
        end
    from (select row_number() over (partition by id order by id,value) as seq, value,id from @digits) data
    where data.id = s.id
    group by value - seq
    for xml path('')
)), 1, 1, '') as result from @digits s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @digits table (id int,value int )
insert @digits values (1,80),(1,90),(1,100),(1,200),(1,210),(1,9),(1,10),(1,12),
(2,8),(2,9),(2,11),(2,12),
(3,2),(3,4),(3,5),(3,7)

select distinct id,stuff(convert(varchar(max),
(
    select 
        ',' + case 
            when min(value) = max(value) then convert(varchar(10), min(value)) 
            else convert(varchar(10), min(value)) + '-' + convert(varchar(10), max(value)) 
        end
    from (select row_number() over (partition by id order by id,value) as seq, value,id from @digits) data
    where data.id = s.id
    group by (value/10) - seq
    for xml path('')
)), 1, 1, '') as result from @digits s
```